# What happens to IBAN if the code owner dies?

Tags: iban

The bank account of the dead person ceases to exist. What happens to iban status after that? 'Invalid' and unavailable (when i'm checking the number)?

Comment: Why do you think anything happens to it? IBAN identifies a bank account, and is probably valid as long as the bank account exists. Some bank accounts may be closed after the owner dies, but it depends on the account.

Comment: Thanks @DJClayworth for the answer. 
"probably valid as long as the bank account exists" - that's the thing. I suppose i should specify it. The bank account of the dead person ceases to exist. What happens to iban status after that? 'Invalid' and unavailable (when i'm checking the number)? I need to know exactly, i'm sorry, that's important.

Comment: That's not exactly what's in the question. Can you edit the question to ask that?

Comment: The difference between "_closed_" and "_locked_" probably also comes into play. When my parents died in close succession, their joint account was "locked" (so no money could leave) on notification of the fist death, and only closed after the second death and my brother and I registered as next-of-kin. Although the situation didn't arise, I'm pretty sure that if any money had been received while locked, it would have been accepted by the bank. To save the question being closed, you'll need to add more details and which country (and state if appropriate) as laws / regulations may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When someone dies, then their bank account does not get terminated immediately. First the bank does actually need to get notified of the death, which in many countries does not happen automatically. Then control over the account is transferred to the estate of the deceased, which can then decide what to do with it (keep using it or terminating it).

When an account gets terminated (for whatever reason), then the IBAN becomes invalid. Any attempt to wire money to the account or to direct-debit the account will be rejected.

However, a bank can later reissue an IBAN number after an account was terminated. I know that because I actually had to write a program once to terminate long unused IBAN numbers in a bookkeeping system. A wire transfer got to a wrong person, because they got a reused IBAN number from a very old business partner of our client. But banks usually wait a couple years before they do that to avoid any trouble from misrouted wire transfers or direct debits.   One bank told us that they block previously used account numbers for 5 years. But I am not sure if this is more or less than the industry standard. I would assume that banks with fewer customers or which don't yet exist for long have enough account numbers left that there is no need for them to reuse old ones.

Comment: My biggest thanks for an extensive response. Really helpful. I reached out to a bank officer (Deutsche Bank), she said they don't receive this information automatically, so the process can take any time.